# not able to select row which is not exist but need to manipulate data and fetch it into excel sheet

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, wpf

I am having Company and module table. There are 11 modules total. Each company has status column 'Active and Inactive'. Scenario is if a company belongs to Module 1,3,5,7,9 so i have to select these as well as all the rest 2,4,6,8,10,11 modules with Status 'Inactive .

please help how to do this. attaching screenshot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hfPy.png)

Comment: Provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts, not pictures, and show desired result for this data.

Comment: in screenshot we can see that for company id 101613 and for year 2018 data is not available for 7,8,9,10,11,12 module so i have to select row with this moduleid and make status id = 0 which means inactive